# Home page block order

Tags: magento

I would like to change the order of some blocks in our Magento environment.
I've opened nearly every layout XML, but I can't find what I am looking for.

Does anyone know where to start looking for the order of the blocks?

Answer (score 0):

Anything front-end or design related is under app/design/frontend (for general site) and app/design/adminhtml for the admin panel.

The next folder you navigate to is the package you use, you can check this under the design tab of the system config of the admin panel. So for example if it is base, you go to the app/design/frontend/base

Next folder is the theme, you can check it in the design tab too. So assume it's the default theme it would be like app/design/frontend/base/default

Now go to the layout folder and find the .xml for the page you looking for.  If its a product page it would be the app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog.xml

Comment: Thans Cleong for your response,
I am looking for the home page, and not for the product pages.
The problem is that I don't know which template file it is.

Comment: You have to go to the admin panel -> CMS -> and change the layout for the homepage, remember to match it with the page.xml if your changing the columns